# How to get jekyll to compile my sass when it changes?

Tags: sass, rubygems, jekyll, github-pages

I have a github pages site using the jekyll cayman theme, and I set up a sass stylesheet at `assets/css/style.scss`

Its contents begin:

```
---
# Front matter comment to ensure Jekyll properly reads file.
---
//DON'T DELETE THE ABOVE

@import "jekyll-theme-cayman";
```

and then I have the rest of my sass.

I then run `bundle exec jekyll serve`.

This used to work to start a server, and watch changes to the sass file and compile them to `_site/assets/css/style.css`.

I can see that it is picking up that there are changes in the sass file - the console logs: `Regenerating: 1 file(s) changed at 2022-10-28 21:22:54 assets/css/style.scss` - but nothing gets output to the `style.css` file. I've tried running `bundle exec jekyll serve --watch`.

That no longer works, and I'm not sure why. I noticed when I tried to run this for the first time in a while, it complained about nokogiri, so I ran bundle install - maybe that messed things up?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `bundle exec jekyll clean && bundle exec jekyll serve` or one command after the other. Clean removes files and cleans Sass and Jekyll caches. See https://jekyllrb.com/docs/usage/